# Conditionally add to an array

Tags: php, arrays, if-statement

I'm trying to add to an array in a IF condition but it's not appending although i'm in a foreach loop

what I have doesn't append to $connected but the key increments:

```
$key1 = '0';
foreach ($dataNewAndUnlock1 as $key => $val) {
    $stream = ssh2_exec($connection, 'ping -c 1 '. $val);

    stream_set_blocking($stream, true);

    while ($o = fgets($stream)) {
        $connected = array();

        if (strpos($o, 'ttl') !== false) {
            $connected[$key1] = $val;

            echo $val .' EnodeB is connected <br>';
            $key1++;
        }

        if (strpos($o, '0 received') !== false) {
            echo $val .' EnodeB NOT connected <br>';
        }
    }
}
```

$connnected gives something like this, then var_dump is empty at  the end

```
C:\wamp64\www\SendJason2.php:286:
array (size=1)
  0 => string 'XXX.XX.XXX.XXX' (length=14)
C:\wamp64\www\SendJason2.php:286:
array (size=1)
  1 => string 'XXX.XX.XXX.XX' (length=13)
C:\wamp64\www\SendJason2.php:286:
array (size=1)
  2 => string 'XXX.XX.XXX.XXX' (length=14)
C:\wamp64\www\SendJason2.php:286:
array (size=1)
  3 => string 'XXX.XX.XXX.XXX' (length=14)
C:\wamp64\www\SendJason2.php:286:
array (size=1)
  4 => string 'XXX.XX.XXX.XXX' (length=14)
...

C:\wamp64\www\SendJason2.php:306:
array (size=0)
  empty
```

Comment: Is the `$val` actually pushing data out?

Comment: Why do you initialize `$key1` with the string `0` and then use `$key1++`?

Comment: Small note: Dont put your code in the `C:\wamp64\www` folder. Thats reserved for WAMPServer.. Make a subfolder for all your projects or better still a Virtual Host in a totally seperate folder

Comment: Thanks Sean! really appreciated both comments worked

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are overwriting `$connected` with an empty array each time your `foreach` loop iterates. Move the assignment of `$connected` to before your `foreach` loop.

```
$key1 = '0';
$connected = array();
foreach ($dataNewAndUnlock1 as $key => $val) {
    ...
```

Also, to append to an array, you don't need to maintain your own index, you can just use this syntax:

```
$connected[] = $val;
```